# A problem from Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

A bounded operator on Hilbert space(say $H$) $A$ is said to be ***reductive*** if every invariant subspace for $A$ reduces $A$. ( we say a subspace $V\subset H$ reduces $A$ if $A(V)\subset V$ and $A(V^\perp)\subset V^\perp$)

This definition is given in the book "A course in Functional Analysis" chapter IX section 9 (9.1 Definition).

In the book the next paragraph states that -**every normal compact operator is reductive**.

Somehow I was unable to find out an argument to prove this. I was able to find an argument for finite dimensional case. Some hint would also be very helpful.

Comment: Invariant subspace for $A$ reduces $A$. What does this mean?

Comment: @user839372 I have edited the question for you